# Filter strings by its time content in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a string vector (file names actually):

```
x<-c("abcd20090809.txt", "bc20100209.txt", "bcd19971109.txt",
     "abcef20120802.txt", "efg20151109.txt","xyz19860102.txt")
```

The numbers in `x` represent the time in format of `yyyymmdd`. What I wanted is to filter the `x` for the files's time before year `2000`. e.g. an output would be:

```
> xx
[1] "bcd19971109.txt" "xyz19860102.txt"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep`

```
grep(pattern = "^[a-z]+1", x, value = TRUE)
# [1] "bcd19971109.txt" "xyz19860102.txt"
```

**edit**

If we want to subset by the condition 'before 2010' we might do

```
thres <- as.Date("2010-01-01")
idx <- as.Date(unlist(regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\d+", text = x), )), format = "%Y%m%d") < thres
x[idx]
# [1] "abcd20090809.txt" "bcd19971109.txt"  "xyz19860102.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is probably by coincidence. What if before say 2010?

Answer (score 1):

Here, I use `substring` to pull out the year and then I check it against your condition (i.e., < 2000) and pull out the elements of `x` that are `TRUE`.

```r
x<-c("abcd20090809.txt", "bc20100209.txt", "bcd19971109.txt",
     "abcef20120802.txt", "efg20151109.txt","xyz19860102.txt")

x[as.numeric(substring(x,nchar(x)-11,nchar(x)-8))<2000]
#> [1] "bcd19971109.txt" "xyz19860102.txt"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>